# get all os.date tags as table in lua

Tags: date, datetime, lua

`os.date("!*t")` in lua return a table like this:

```
year    a full year
month   01-12
day 01-31
hour    00-23
min 00-59
sec 00-59
isdst   a boolean, true if daylight saving
```

But we have some variable that not present in this table like timezone, start week etc...
We can get them by `os.date(%z %p)`, but is there any way to get a more complete version of the above table with `os.date` or any other internal library?

I want just run one time `os.date()` inside my code, and avoid running that for second time to get ‍‍‍‍`os.date(%z %p)`
is there any way to get a complete table of all available tags?

Base of [lua document](https://www.lua.org/pil/22.1.html) avilabel tag is

```
%a  abbreviated weekday name (e.g., Wed)
%A  full weekday name (e.g., Wednesday)
%b  abbreviated month name (e.g., Sep)
%B  full month name (e.g., September)
%c  date and time (e.g., 09/16/98 23:48:10)
%d  day of the month (16) [01-31]
%H  hour, using a 24-hour clock (23) [00-23]
%I  hour, using a 12-hour clock (11) [01-12]
%M  minute (48) [00-59]
%m  month (09) [01-12]
%p  either "am" or "pm" (pm)
%S  second (10) [00-61]
%w  weekday (3) [0-6 = Sunday-Saturday]
%x  date (e.g., 09/16/98)
%X  time (e.g., 23:48:10)
%Y  full year (1998)
%y  two-digit year (98) [00-99]
%%  the character `%´
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua is ANSI C compatible.

That means Lua does not provide access to **extra** `struct tm` fields from `glibc` in it's standard lib (see https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ctime.3.html#NOTES)

If you want to utilize these **extra** `struct tm` glibc fields:

```c
long tm_gmtoff;           /* Seconds east of UTC */
const char *tm_zone;      /* Timezone abbreviation */
```

Then, as @Piglet already mentioned, You'll need to implement it yourself.

You can either patch an original Lua source here:
https://github.com/lua/lua/blob/master/loslib.c#L230
(which is a bad decision in general), or you can write your own glibc-dependent lua c module, which is way better.

Answer (score 2):

From [Lua 5.4 Reference Manual: os.date:](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-os.date)

> If format starts with '!', then the date is formatted in Coordinated
> Universal Time. After this optional character, if format is the string
> "*t", then date returns a table with the following fields: year, month
> (1–12), day (1–31), hour (0–23), min (0–59), sec (0–61, due to leap
> seconds), wday (weekday, 1–7, Sunday is 1), yday (day of the year,
> 1–366), and isdst (daylight saving flag, a boolean). This last field
> may be absent if the information is not available.

If you want the table to contain more fields, you need to implement this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before 'If you want the table to contain more fields, you need to implement this yourself.'

And i love Lua for that.
Its so easy...

```
> dtable = setmetatable(os.date('!*t'), {__call = function(self) self.tz=os.date('%z') self.ampam = os.date('%p') return self end})
> dir = function(tab) for k, v in pairs(tab) do print(k, '=>', v) end end
> dir(dtable)
wday    =>  6
yday    =>  294
hour    =>  19
isdst   =>  false
day =>  21
sec =>  22
month   =>  10
min =>  3
year    =>  2022
> dir(dtable())
wday    =>  6
ampam   =>  PM
tz  =>  +0200
yday    =>  294
hour    =>  19
isdst   =>  false
day =>  21
sec =>  22
month   =>  10
min =>  3
year    =>  2022
```

So after above check/control a simple...

```
dtable = setmetatable(os.date('!*t'), {__call = function(self) self.tz=os.date('%z') self.ampam = os.date('%p') return self end})
dtable = dtable()
```

...extend the table.

Tip: Ever tried `os.setlocale()`?

```
> os.setlocale('de_DE.utf8','time')
de_DE.utf8
> dir(dtable())
wday    =>  6
ampam   =>  
tz  =>  +0200
yday    =>  294
hour    =>  19
isdst   =>  false
day =>  21
sec =>  22
month   =>  10
min =>  3
year    =>  2022
> os.setlocale('ja_JP.utf8','time')
ja_JP.utf8
> dir(dtable())
wday    =>  6
ampam   =>  午後
tz  =>  +0200
yday    =>  294
hour    =>  19
isdst   =>  false
day =>  21
sec =>  22
month   =>  10
min =>  3
year    =>  2022
```

...it is worth as argument for the `__call` metamethod...

```
__call = function(self, locale)
local locale = locale or 'en_US.utf8'
os.setlocale(locale, 'time')
self.tz = os.date('%z')
self.ampam = os.date('%p')
return self
end
```

And with a more extended dtable.lua and dir.lua you can do like...

```
dir(dtable('de_DE.utf8'))
1   z (string) => +0200 (string) 5 byte
2   B (string) => Oktober (string) 7 byte
3   b (string) => Okt (string) 3 byte
4   hour (string) => 20 (number) integer
5   A (string) => Freitag (string) 7 byte
6   month (string) => 10 (number) integer
7   isdst (string) => false (boolean)
8   min (string) => 29 (number) integer
9   p (string) =>  (string) 0 byte
10  sec (string) => 52 (number) integer
11  a (string) => Fr (string) 2 byte
12  day (string) => 21 (number) integer
13  year (string) => 2022 (number) integer
14  yday (string) => 294 (number) integer
15  wday (string) => 6 (number) integer
> dir(dtable('ja_JP.utf8'))
1   z (string) => +0200 (string) 5 byte
2   B (string) => 10月 (string) 5 byte
3   b (string) => 10月 (string) 5 byte
4   hour (string) => 20 (number) integer
5   A (string) => 金曜日 (string) 9 byte
6   month (string) => 10 (number) integer
7   isdst (string) => false (boolean)
8   min (string) => 29 (number) integer
9   p (string) => 午後 (string) 6 byte
10  sec (string) => 52 (number) integer
11  a (string) => 金 (string) 3 byte
12  day (string) => 21 (number) integer
13  year (string) => 2022 (number) integer
14  yday (string) => 294 (number) integer
15  wday (string) => 6 (number) integer
```